# FileInputStream for a generic file System

Tags: java, filesystems, hdfs

I have a file that contains java serialized objects like "Vector". I have stored this file over Hadoop Distributed File System(HDFS). Now I intend to read this file (using method readObject) in one of the map task. I suppose

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("hdfs/path/to/file");
```

wont' work as the file is stored over HDFS. So I thought of using org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem class. But Unfortunately it does not have any method that returns FileInputStream. All it has is a method that returns FSDataInputStream but I want a inputstream that can read serialized java objects like vector from a file rather than just primitive data types that FSDataInputStream would do.

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FileInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) doesn't give you facitily to read serialized objects directly. You need to wrap it into [ObjectInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). You can do the same with [FSDataInputStream](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.16.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream.html), just wrap it into [ObjectInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and then you can read your objects from it.

In other words, if you have `fileSystem` of type `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`, just use:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileSystem.open(path));
```

Comment: Using CDH5 this results an error.
`fcont=hfs.FileContext.getFileContext();
f=fcont.open(hfs.Path('/tmp/test.txt'));
ois = java.io.ObjectInputStream(f);
`
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 6C6F6700

Comment: @Andor: I've been getting the same exception and have been trying to figure out a solution since a couple of days, without any luck. Were you able to find out what was the problem?

Comment: My Java guru colleagues said that's not possible, so I have looked for an other way, which was the NFS gateway of HDFS. Though I'm convinced, that if the interface is appropriate, this should work also.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the FSDataInputStream like this (scala code)

```
val hadoopConf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new     java.net.URI("hdfs://nameserv"), hadoopConf)

val in = hdfs.open(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://nameserv/somepath/myfile")).asInstanceOf[java.io.InputStream]
```