# Read a properties file from HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system, distributed-filesystem

I'm trying to read a Java properties file that is on HDFS like this:

```
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("hdfs://user/hdfs/my_props.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Properties file not found.");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I get the "Properties file not found." exception. If I replace the path to a local file, it works fine and I'm able to read the file.

Is it possible to read a HDFS file using FileInputStream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you need to use hadoop jars and also need the FileSystem to read from HDFS. Something like this should be put before your code.

```
Path pt=new Path("hdfs://user/hdfs/my_props.properties");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
```

Refer to: [FileInputStream for a generic file System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839878/fileinputstream-for-a-generic-file-system)

Comment: I get "Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hdfs/my_props.properties, expected: hdfs://nameservice" exception. Any ideas how to set it the path correctly?

Comment: Worked after passing the namenode:8020/path/to/file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration)
 val hdfsPath = new Path("hdfs://user/hdfs/my_props.properties")
 val fis = new InputStreamReader(fs.open(hdfsPath))
 prop.load(fis) // This will be your properties object
```